# Difference between signed main() and int main()?

Tags: c++, int, program-entry-point, signed

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define int long long
typedef pair<int,int> pint;
typedef vector<int> vint;
typedef vector<pint> vpint;

#define rep(i,n) for(int i = 0; i < (n); i++)

int main()
{
    vint A(3), B(3);
    rep(i, 3) cin>> A[i];
    rep(i, 3) cin >> B[i];
    int pa = 0, pb = 0;
    rep(i, 3) {
        if(A[i] > B[i]) pa++;
        else if(A[i] < B[i]) pb++;
    }
    cout << pa << " " << pb << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When using `int main()`, the compiler shows an error message "main must return int", but when I replace it with `signed main()`, there is no error. What's the reason?

Comment: `signed` and `unsigned` default to `signed int` and `unsigned int` if you do not specify any other type.

Comment: `#define int long long` Doctor, I shot myself in the foot. Could you tell me why it hurts?

Answer (score 6):

`int main` doesn't return `int` - it returns `long long`. You have defined a macro named `int`.

Speaking of which, defining a macro with the name that matches a keyword exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define int long long
```

Why on earth would you do that????

```
typedef pair<int,int>pint;
```

Don't do that. Type `pair<int, int>`; dont be lazy. Also, you're making the code convoluted just to define `pint` (which any reasonable person would assume "pointer to int") just not to use it.

```
typedef vector<int>vint;
typedef vector<pint>vpint;
```

Ditto. Don't do that.

```
#define rep(i,n) for(int i=0;i<(n);i++)
```

No. No. Please, don't do that.

```
int main()
```

You defined `int` to be something else. You already broke C by this point.

```
vint A(3),B(3);
```

Please, take the time to type `vector<int>` instead of `vint`, and please, initialize each variable on its own line.

```
rep(i,3)cin>>A[i];
```

Does this seem clear to you? I don't even know if I want to know what it does. Don't use macros. Please.

```
int pa=0,pb=0;
```

Also, besides putting each initialization on its own line, and recall you defined `int` to be `long long`, please be consistent: `A` is a variable and you're naming it with capital letters, but here you're not using capital letters. Try to chose any rule you want, but be *consistent*. Like, "all clases with capital letters and all variables start with lowercase".

Indent properly, please. And put some spaces, they don't charge you by character. If you can, put braces always. Instead of this:

```
rep(i,3) {
    if(A[i]>B[i])pa++;
    else if(A[i]<B[i])pb++;
}
```

Just put this:

```
for (int i= 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if (A[i] > B[i]) {
        pa++;
    } else if (A[i] < B[i]) {
        pb++;
    }
}
```

Also, as `A` and `B` have `size()` member:

```
for (size_t i= 0; i < min(A.size(), B.size()); ++i) {
    if (A[i] > B[i]) {
        pa++;
    } else if (A[i] < B[i]) {
        pb++;
    }
}
```

And in that way, if you change `A(3)` and `B(3)` to be `A(5)` and `B(5)`, you don't have to search for the `3` in the `for`. Also, it would be better to have:

```
static const auto n= 3;
vector<int> A(n);
vector<int> B(n);
```

Assuming they always are going to be the same size.

Spaces, pleaseeeeee:

```
cout << pa << " " << pb << endl;
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't get the question. I asked why signed main() did the work but using int main() it shows error. Oh pleaseeeeeeeeee read it properly.

Comment: Not to mention all that is wrong with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`..

Comment: @shubh "Seems like you didn't get the question. I asked why signed main() did the work but using int main() it shows error" - that would be the `#define int long long` bit.

Comment: @user11920318 Yes, I read it. I understood it. But not commenting the rest was like entering on a house that's on fire and pointing at the stain that you missed while cleaning the carpet. That code is a mess. Is a no-no in so many levels. Besides, the part where you "broke C" is clear, I think.

Comment: Really late to the conversation, but thought I might chime in. This kind of abbreviated code is very common in competitive programming, where we want to type things as fast as possible. Generics can take a lot of time to type so we save anything we can, take a look at my template: pastebin.com/zQSJMxvG // Don't worry, I don't use any of that at work ;)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't want to #define stuff that will be used in your code, as it can cause unforeseen issues resulting in errors. Something I commonly come across is:

```
#define max(a,b)(a<b?a:b)
```

which prevents anyone from writing a function named 'max' in any of the code following that definition.

Comment: In particular, you don't want to use `#define` to redefine **any C++ keyword**. That's not allowed. +1.

Comment: As to a function named `max`, if you're desperate, there is a trick you can use: put `max` in parentheses wherever you use it as an ordinary name. `(max)` won't trigger the function-like macro, because there is no `(` following `max`.